# Wix Installer v3 - Embed Browser

Tags: wix

I have been searching for this for days, and I can't seem to find anything that would solve this.

I have a requirement to show a web browser control in a Wix installer dialog that shows the application's Terms of Service web page.

We DON'T want to use the standard EULA page, which simply displays a compiled in RTF file, because the terms can change from time to time and we don't want to have to rebuild the installer each time just for that.

From what I can see, there are options for creating custom dialogs, but that seems like a lot of work for changing one thing. We really don't want to have to redesign the whole installer.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

Windows installer can only show RTF or plain text, that is included in the package. It cannot show a web site, and you cannot define a custom page that would support a custom control, such as an embedded web browser because custom controls are not supported.

Comment: I'm taking about the Wix Installer, not Windows Installer

Comment: Wix is a tool that creates packages for windows installer (MSI packages). So it can't do more than windows installer supports. Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer

Answer (score 1):

This is not less work but you can create a bundle in WiX and a custom BootstrapperApplication to implement whatever UI you want.